# Updating multiple rows at once having different value for each row

Tags: oracle10g, plpgsql

I have one master table. its primary key is used as foreign key in other tables. I can not modify the definition of the other tables as it does not have any "on update cascade" and i want to change the primary key's value so the other tables i should update...
currently i have written the plpgsql, 
but as I have large amount of data to process, somehow it is slowing down the performance.
Can someone help me, how to update multiple table in single query, or updating multiple rows of-course with different values?

Comment: Are you aware that `plpgsql`is the procedural language of PostgreSQL, while the one for Oracle is called `plsql`? This confusion might explain why you never got a satisfying answer. Which is it, really?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option to update multiple rows in one statement:

```
update mytable set
mycolumn = (case myid when 1 then 'a' when 2 then 'b' ... end)
where myid in (1, 2, ...);
```

Comment: I cant have this as i will be updating millions of records and all I will be updating with formula based on other columns value.

Comment: and i should update the child tables as well..
like
update childtable1 set col1=col2(which value I am taking into one of the plpgsql variable) where col1=table1.col1
update childtable2 set col1=col2(which value I am taking into one of the plpgsql variable) where col1=table1.col1